# Linux command for extract file names in mutiple directories

Tags: shell, command

I have multiple directories with identical suffix containing the same file name.
Let's say I have files like below.

```
~/test/sample1/test.txt
~/test/sample2/test.txt
~/test/sample3/test.txt
~/test/sample4/test.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is simply print the list of the paths and file names into a txt file, so I tried..

```
for t in ~/test/sample*/test/txt; do echo $t >> result.txt; done
```

but got nothing.

How can I make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the find command here.

Go to the parent directory from where you want to search and execute the below command.

> find . -name "test.txt" > result.txt

Comment: That's simple, easy, and awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes in your  "for t in ~/test/sample*/test/txt; do echo $t >> result.txt; done"

"for t in ~/test/sample*/test.txt; do echo $t >> result.txt; done"

This should work for you.

thanks

Comment: I mis-typed the command. I actually typed what you wrote. Thanks!